# get value of export_includes for target

Tags: waf

I have a target in waf defined like this:

```
bld(...,
    target='asdf',
    export_includes='.'
)
```

I want to get the value of the `export_includes` for that target (for use in some custom commands).

How do I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom rule with the features for whatever target you're processing. Ex, let's say I'm processing C:

```
def print_includes(t):
    print(t.env.INCPATHS)
bld(features='c', use='asdf', rule=print_includes)
```

The task `t`'s `env` will contain all relevant environment variables as derived from the `bld.env`, but with all the additional flags stemming from `use`-ing the target.

i.e. if I originally had `bld.env.INCPATHS == ['old-path' 'other-old-path']`, it'll end up being printed out as `['old-path', 'other-old-path', 'export_include_for_asdf_here']`.